# compile C code in LaTeX file edited by VIM

Tags: vim, macros

My C code is in a LaTeX file I am editing with VIM, and is between marks `'m` and `'n`. It contains LaTeX formatting commands which have to be first deleted, etc. Thus I need to pipe (as standard input) the code between `'m` and `'n` to my external Windows program `mergeC.exe` (written in C) which should, after the necessary transformation, store the correct code into file `PROG.c`, where `PROG` should be replaced with the content of VIM register `"p` (for example, the file name should be `SmithNormal.c`). Subsequently, `PROG.c` should be compiled by executing the shell command `gcc PROG.c -o PROG.exe`. I would like to store a VIM command (macro) into register `"g` such that writing `@g` would perform these two operations.

I am a beginner level VIM user. I can write `:'m,'nw !mergeC`, which works, but don't know how to pass the name in register `"p` to `mergeC` (it should be like `mergeC PROG` where `PROG` would be stored into `argv[1]`).

I have experimented with commands like

```
:'m,'n w !mergeC getreg('p')
```

which resulted in error messages.

Comment: Your code :execute "'n,'mw !mergeC ".getreg('p') works fine. I only would like to add something to achieve the second part of my task, namely compile the output of mergeC with the command "gcc PROG.c -o PROG.exe" where PROG should be, as before, getreg('p').

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

`:help getreg()` is the correct way to retrieve the content of a register but, after `:!`, the only expressions that are evaluated are `%` and friends
(see `:help cmdline-special`) so `getreg('p')` will be passed directly to the shell, which doesn't know what to do with it.

In order to get the content of `getreg('p')` in that `:!` command, you need `:help :execute`:

```
:execute "'n,'mw !mergeC " . getreg("p")
```

which evaluates `getreg('p')` before concatenating the result with the rest of the command, and then executes the full command.

I don't have your `mergeC` command so I improvised a contrived example below:

[image: w!]

Your problem, now, is putting that in a register. I would suggest a recording in this case because setting the register manually might prove complicated, due to all the quotes and special characters:

```
qg                                          " start recording in register "g
:execute "'n,'mw !mergeC ".getreg('p')<CR>  " do your thing
q                                           " stop recording
```

Comment: In VIM of LaTeX file:

:exe "'m,'nw !x ".getreg('p')

In batch script x.bat two commands:

@findstr "^" | mergeC %1
gcc %1.c -o %1.exe

This works, but could it be done without x.bat?